# Direct object instantiation is discouraged in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

As per magento marketplace standards I just cannot instantiate object of class as below. I have checked with various files of core and found that magento itself uses new keyword to instantiate. The code check can be ignored by adding `// @codingStandardsIgnoreStart and // @codingStandardsIgnoreEnd` but wanted to know if we have any other way.

```
//Below is the class
OAuth\Common\Consumer\Credentials

//Below is the object
$foo_object = new Credentials($this->getconsumerId(),
                              $this->getconsumerSecret(),
                              $this->getcallbackUrl());
```

Comment: Did you find out solution of this question?

Comment: as per below answer, solution is not working in Magento-2.1.x. if you have any solution please share here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as soon as you use the new keyword, you loose all benefits of dependency injection and the magento object manager.

There is a pretty easy (and mostly the correct) way to instantiate any [non-injectable](http://inchoo.net/magento-2/basics-dependency-injection-usage-magento-2/) object with a factory. You should always try to use [factories](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/factories.html) and do not instantiate them with the `new` keyword or by calling the objectmanager directly.

Just inject `OAuth\Common\Consumer\CredentialsFactory` in your constructor.

The Magento objectmanager will automatically create this factory for your object (by naming convention)

you can then call the `create` method on the factory and pass in your arguments as an associated array

```
$credentials = $this->credentialsFactory->create([
    'consumerId' => $this->getConsumerId(),
    'consumerSecret' => $this->getConsumerSecret(),
    'callbackUrl' => $this->getCallbackUrl()
]);
```

The array keys here have to match the constructor parameters ob the original Credentials Class

Here is an example including the constructor injection

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module

class Class
{
    /** @var \OAuth\Common\Consumer\CredentialsFactory */
    private $credentialsFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \OAuth\Common\Consumer\CredentialsFactory $credentialsFactory
    ) {
        $this->credentialsFactory = $credentialsFactory;
    }

    public function getCredentials($consumerId, $consumerSecret, $callbackUrl): \OAuth\Common\Consumer\Credentials
    {
        $this->credentialsFactory->create([
            'consumerId' => $consumerId,
            'consumerSecret' => $consumerSecret,
            'callbackUrl' => $callbackUrl
        ]);
    }
}
```

[Here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/factories.html) you find the magento documentation on factories and also on when they can be auto generated

Comment: I have same code used but not working with 2.1.x version. Can you please share your suggestion for this version?